# Unable to get HiddenField from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net application with listview and HiddenField inside itemtemplate.
I try to get the value from the HiddenField by Javascript but it throws an Exception which the HiddenField doesn't exist. I call the script function from a button click inside user a control so the call for the function doesn't supposed to happen until the click. It probably throws it during the binding.

Thank You !

```
<LayoutTemplate>
  <table runat="server" id="table1">
    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
  </table>
</LayoutTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
  <cusItem:CustomerItem ID="cusItemList" runat="server" />
  <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCus" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("ID")%>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

The Java sctript is:

```
function userSelected() {
        var v = document.getElementById("<%= hdfCus.ClientID %>");
        if (v == undefined)
            alert("no");
        else
            alert("yes");
    }
```

Comment: Is the id `hdfCus` changing?

Comment: Then you should have `<%= hdfCus.ClientID %>` in the `<asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCus"` also i think

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, where should I have the <%= hdfCus.ClientID %>?  Do you mean inside the ID of the HiddenField?

Comment: I mean the hidden field's ID. In your post there is only one id and you look for different IDs with `document.getElementById("<%= hdfCus.ClientID %>");`

Comment: @Jacob: controls inside container like gridview are not accessible this way. Even inside asp.net code, you have to loop through controls collection to get them.